# Azure AD B2C vulnerable to Open Redirect?

Tags: azure, redirect, logout, azure-ad-b2c

I am using OWIN & OpenId to authenticate users for my web application using Azure AD B2C, the Startup.Auth.cs has code like so :

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                 MetadataAddress = string.Format(AadInstance, Tenant, policy),
                AuthenticationType = policy,
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifica....
```

On signout, it causes a redirect to the postLogoutRedirectUrl like so

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_TENANT/oauth2/logout?p=my_policy&post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F

The post logout redirect URI is present in the redirect Uri in the portal.

If I stop the browser and change the post logout uri in the address bar to https%3A%2F%2Fevil.com%2F, the redirect happens properly even though this url https://evil.com/ is not in the allowed redirect uri.

Why is AD B2C not stopping the redirect ? is this not open to vulnerability ?

Comment: I fail to see the vulnerability. The whole session is running over HTTPS. If the URL is modified in flight, then either your app is compromised, or the users client is compromised. In either of these cases redirecting after logout would be the least of my concerns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you sign in using Azure AD B2C, the B2C service sends a token to the "redirect_uri" (the app). Since a token needs to remain secure, the B2C service asks you to whitelist the URL's where it should send the token to.

When you are signing out, nothing secure is being transmitted from the B2C service back to the app. Therefore, even if a user is redirected to a malicious site, nothing secure is lost.

Comment: It doesn’t look good if someone intercepts this request and redirects to malicious website. For the user who has no clue it appears as if our website redirected. This could very well be a phishing site designed to look like my web app

Comment: Intercepting would mean getting past HTTPS.

Comment: @Vicky As others have stated, there would have to be a man in the middle TLS attack for this to take place. Even such, as parakh stated, nothing secure would be lost.

Comment: It is not considered like a vulnerability? I mean if an attacker success to redirect a user (through an email for example) on his websites, he can through social engineering obtain the credentials of a user (for example, the attacker build a login form identical to the website with a URL resembling to the vulnerable website).

Answer (score 2):

You can change this behavior to force Azure AD B2C to only process the logout re-direct if a valid ID token is passed in as a parameter in the sign out request.  To get B2C to automatically include the ID token, and check for its existence, simply edit your sign-in / sign-up policy within the Azure Portal, ie:

[image]

Alternatively, if you are using custom policies, you can add the `SingleSignOn` element to the `UserJourneyBehaviors` section, and set the `EnforceIdTokenHintOnLogout` to true, ie:

```
<UserJourneyBehaviors>
     <SingleSignOn Scope="Tenant" EnforceIdTokenHintOnLogout="true" />

</UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

Comment: for the custom policy fix, if you just add that line and nothing else, when you sign out you get an error 'The id_token_hint parameter has not been specified in the request. Please provide token and try again.'  how do you provide the id_token_hint?